# JSON.stringify no realiza saltos de linea pero los muestra en /n

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

El stringify me esta devolviendo el string de la forma incorrecta y no se cual seria el motivo .

```
app.get('/info' , async (req , res)=>{
    let info = {};
    

    try {
        // Lectura de archivo
        let datos = await fs.promises.readFile('./package.json','utf-8');
        let stats = fs.statSync("./package.json")
        let datosParce=  JSON.parse(datos)
        info.contenidoStr=JSON.stringify(datosParce,null,2)
        info.contenidoObj=datosParce
        info.size= JSON.parse(stats["size"])
        console.log(info);

        // escritura
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./info.txt', JSON.stringify(info, null, 2));
      
        res.json(info)
    

    }

    catch(error){

        res.status(500).send(`Error de lectura o escritura del archivo ${error}`)
    }

})
```

El resultado de contenidoStr me muestra los saltos de linea con las \n y no tal cual esta en el package json .

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me puedo estar equivacando, pero según yo es porque estás haciendo una doble codificación, primero en `info.contenidoStr=JSON.stringify(datosParce,null,2)` y luego cuando los escribes en disco con `JSON.stringify(info, null, 2)` por lo que los caráteres se están escapando (razón por la que hay un escape en el salto de línea `\\n`).

Comment: correcto, estas codificando dos veces tus bytes si deseas mantenerlo asi puedes realizar un replace a tu texto y poner en blanco las coincidencias con \n

Comment: Gracias  , corregí lo que me indicaron y se quitaron las contrabarras que estaban de mas pero me quedaron algunas y siguen estando los \n . Intente quitarlas con replace como me indicaron pero me borra todo lo que tengo por debajo de la primera linea . Soy nuevo en javascript , gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya he captado lo que quieres hacer, pero al parecer estás un poco confundido. He replicado tu código y he hecho algunas modificaciones.

- La primera es que ya que estás usando *promises* no le veo ventaja a usar `statsSync` ya que lo ideal entonces sería que también uses el método asíncrono.
- He eliminado el `JSON.stringify()` en la asignación a `info.contenidoStr`, ya que recordemos que este string (`datos`) es una representación tal cual se encuentra en *package.json* por lo que es inncesario volver a aplicarle un formato.
- Debido a que `fs.promises.stat()` devuelve un objeto, es redundante hacer un `JSON.parse()` ya que al ser ya un objeto, puedes acceder a la propiedad `size` directamente.

```javascript
const fs = require('fs');

async function main() {
  try {
    let info = {};
    const datos = await fs.promises.readFile('./package.json', 'utf-8');
    const stats = await fs.promises.stat('./package.json')
    const datosParse = JSON.parse(datos);

    info.contenidoStr = datos;
    info.contenidoObj = datosParse;
    info.size = stats.size;

    await fs.promises.writeFile('./info.txt', JSON.stringify(info, null, 2));

    console.log(info.contenidoStr);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

main();
```

Vale, ahora veamos lo que la función `fs.promises.writeFile()` ha hecho y demos un vistazo al contenido del archivo *info.txt*.

```
{
  "contenidoStr": "{\n  \"name\": \"read-write-files\",\n  \"version\": \"1.0.0\",\n  \"description\": \"\",\n  \"main\": \"readfiles.js\",\n  \"scripts\": {\n    \"test\": \"echo \\\"Error: no test specified\\\" && exit 1\"\n  },\n  \"author\": \"\",\n  \"license\": \"ISC\"\n}\n",
  "contenidoObj": {
    "name": "read-write-files",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "readfiles.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
  },
  "size": 216
}
```

Justo aquí es en donde nos encontramos con el supuesto "error" que comentas, lo cual no es un error, pues es el comportamiento esperado. Recuerda que es un `string`, por lo que en términos generales, debe representar una copia de lo que se encuentra en el archivo de origen. Ahora si observas en el código, notarás un `console.log()` de la variable `info.contenidoStr`, veamos que nos muestra esa impresión:

```
{
  "name": "read-write-files",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "readfiles.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Vaya sorpresa ¿no?, el resultado el "igual" a `info.contenidoObj`, no obtenemos resultados *raros*, pero esto se debe a que los carácteres escapados ya han sido interpretados. Este comportamiento se debe a que estás escribiendo (en *info.txt*) un *objeto* y no una simple cadena de texto, `JSON.stringify()` se encarga de escapar los saltos y demás carácteres para evitar un posible error de *parseo* (el famosísimo unexpected token). Si escribieras solo `datos` en lugar de `info` obtendrías el resultado que esperas, pues al tratarse de una cadena común y corriente, pasaría algo similar a lo que sucede con `console.log()`, los carácteres escapados serán interpretados. Haz la prueba y verás.

Por último solo queda ver el contenido de `info` desde consola, que espero que ya lo hayas hecho antes:

```
{
  contenidoStr: '{\n' +
    '  "name": "read-write-files",\n' +
    '  "version": "1.0.0",\n' +
    '  "description": "",\n' +
    '  "main": "readfiles.js",\n' +
    '  "scripts": {\n' +
    '    "test": "echo \\"Error: no test specified\\" && exit 1"\n' +
    '  },\n' +
    '  "author": "",\n' +
    '  "license": "ISC"\n' +
    '}\n',
  contenidoObj: {
    name: 'read-write-files',
    version: '1.0.0',
    description: '',
    main: 'readfiles.js',
    scripts: { test: 'echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1' },
    author: '',
    license: 'ISC'
  },
  size: 216
}
```

Parece ser algo más amigable, pero vuelvo al mismo punto, estamos hablando ya de un objeto y no de una cadena.

Como punto final, si lo que quieres es tener los saltos de línea y tal, entonces no veo la necesidad de tener `contenidoStr`, ya que en `contenidoObj` estás obteniendo la salida que esperas.

Espero que la explicación que hice te ayude a entender un poco mejor la diferencia entre escribir objetos y cadenas de texto a archivos en disco.